# Unable to train simple autoencoder in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, signal-processing, autoencoder

I'm trying to train an autoencoder in Keras for signal processing but I'm somehow failing.

My inputs are segments of 128 frames length for 6 measures (acceleration_x/y/z, gyro_x/y/z), so the overall shape of my dataset is `(22836, 128, 6)` where 22836 is the sample size.

This is the sample code I'm using for the autoencoder:

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = load_dataset()

# reshape the input, whose size is (22836, 128, 6)
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], np.prod(X_train.shape[1:]))
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], np.prod(X_test.shape[1:]))
# now the shape will be (22836, 768)

### MODEL ###
input_shape = [X_train.shape[1]]
X_input = Input(input_shape)

x = Dense(1000, activation='sigmoid', name='enc0')(X_input)
encoded = Dense(350, activation='sigmoid', name='enc1')(x)
x = Dense(1000, activation='sigmoid', name='dec0')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(input_shape[0], activation='sigmoid', name='dec1')(x)

model = Model(inputs=X_input, outputs=decoded, name='autoencoder')

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mean_squared_error')
print(model.summary())
```

The output of `model.summary()` is

```
Model summary
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_55 (InputLayer)        (None, 768)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
enc0 (Dense)                 (None, 1000)              769000    
_________________________________________________________________
enc1 (Dense)                 (None, 350)               350350    
_________________________________________________________________
dec1 (Dense)                 (None, 1000)              351000    
_________________________________________________________________
dec0 (Dense)                 (None, 768)               768768    
=================================================================
Total params: 2,239,118
Trainable params: 2,239,118
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The training is done via

```
# train the model
history = model.fit(x = X_train, y = X_train,
                    epochs=5,
                    batch_size=32,
                    validation_data=(X_test, X_test))
```

where I'm simply trying to learn the identity function which yields:

```
Train on 22836 samples, validate on 5709 samples
Epoch 1/5
22836/22836 [==============================] - 27s 1ms/step - loss: 0.9481 - val_loss: 0.8862
Epoch 2/5
22836/22836 [==============================] - 24s 1ms/step - loss: 0.8669 - val_loss: 0.8358
Epoch 3/5
22836/22836 [==============================] - 25s 1ms/step - loss: 0.8337 - val_loss: 0.8146
Epoch 4/5
22836/22836 [==============================] - 25s 1ms/step - loss: 0.8164 - val_loss: 0.7960
Epoch 5/5
22836/22836 [==============================] - 25s 1ms/step - loss: 0.8004 - val_loss: 0.7819
```

At this point, to try to understand how well it performed, I check the plot of some true inputs vs the predicted ones:

```
prediction = model.predict(X_test)
for i in np.random.randint(0, 100, 7):
    pred = prediction[i, :].reshape(128,6)
    # getting only values for acceleration_x
    pred = pred[:, 0]
    true = X_test[i, :].reshape(128,6)
    # getting only values for acceleration_x
    true = true[:, 0]
    # plot original and reconstructed
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(20, 6))
    ax1.plot(true, color='green')
    ax2.plot(pred, color='red')
```

and these are some of the plots which appear to be completely wrong:

[image: plot1]

[image: plot2]

[image: plot3]

Do you have any suggestion on what's wrong, aside from the small number of epochs (which actually do not seem to make any difference)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is not in the range [0,1] so why do you use `sigmoid` as the activation function in the last layer? Remove the activation function from the last layer (and it might be better to use `relu` in the previous layers).

Also normalize the training data. You can use feature-wise normalization:

```
X_mean = X_train.mean(axis=0)
X_train -= X_mean
X_std = X_train.std(axis=0)
X_train /= X_std + 1e-8
```

And don't forget to use the computed statistics (`X_mean` and `X_std`) in inference time (i.e. testing) to normalize test data.

Comment: you're right about the sigmoid thing... thanks for pointing that out! Instead of normalizing the data as you suggested, would it be the same to use  `BatchNormalization` before every dense layer?

Comment: @crash Batch normalization extends the idea of normalization to the intermediate layers - it does *not* remove the need for normalized inputs.

Comment: @crash As desertnaut mentioned BatchNormalization is usually used for intermediate layers. However you can use it right after the input layer but it **may** degrade the performance and accuracy (experiment it yourself!). Instead, it is much more recommended to normalize your data before feeding it to your model.

Comment: @today Thanks again for the suggestions, it seems already much better now. Can you confirm that I should normalize both train and test (using mean and std computed on training set)?

Comment: @crash You are welcome. Yes, both training and test set should be normalized using the statistics computed on the training data. You should never use the mean and std of test data for normalization of test data (It does not make sense at all).

Comment: Thanks you're a life saver. Just one little side note, I don't think normalizing as you suggested is correct because I would normalize across different sensor measures. Instead I should probably normalize the single features columns `[acc_x, acc_y...., gyr_z]` and then reshape in order to have the `(22836, 768)` input. Is this what you were saying in your answer?

Comment: @crash I suspect that both of them would work since you are using Dense layers and their difference would be negligible in terms of model accuracy. However, you must experiment and try both to confirm this.